# Generating uuid v5 in node.js erros out with no information?

Tags: node.js, uuid

I am using this npm package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

I want to egenrate a v5 uuid.

I can generate a v4 no problem by requiring the module:

```
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
```

and then running:

```
console.log(`uuidv4: ${uuidv4()}`);
```

So then I try to generate a v5:

```
const { v5: uuidV5 } = require('uuid');
const MY_NAMESPACE = 'f709b20b-3353-4c32-8df9-66bc48e91ea9';
var v5uuid = uuidV5('hello', MY_NAMESPACE);
console.log(`userUUID: ${v5uuid}`);
```

However, the app gets to line `var v5uuid = uuidV5('hello', MY_NAMESPACE);` and then goes straight to the catch error. In the variables error says:

**'uuidV5 is not a function'**

running `npm ls uuid`:

```
├─┬ nodemon@1.3.3
│ └─┬ update-notifier@0.1.10
│   └─┬ configstore@0.3.2
│     └── uuid@2.0.3
├─┬ request@2.88.2
│ └── uuid@3.3.2 deduped
├─┬ sequelize@6.14.1
│ └── uuid@8.3.2
└── uuid@3.3.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which OS? Also, if you step into the call with a debugger, where exactly in the library code does it hang?

Comment: @CherryDT macOS 12.4. I have a breakpoint at line `var v5uuid = uuidV5('hello', MY_NAMESPACE);`, then I step into it but it jumps straight to the catch and the error has no information.

Comment: @CherryDT ok, I do see the problem now but I don't understand what I am doing wrong. it says `uuidV5 is not a function`

Comment: Maybe you have a _very_ old version of the `uuid` package? v5 support was added in v3.2.0. The code you posted [works fine](https://runkit.com/cherrydt/62bf6e9f9e0d950009b9f380) on the latest version (v8.3.2). Try `npm ls uuid` to see what version you have.

Comment: @CherryDT Pasted the results in the question.

Comment: Hm, 3.3.2 is newer than 3.2.0 but it's possible that I'm wrong and it wasn't exactly at 3.2.0, some time around that version though. Try updating `uuid` to the latest version. (`npm i uuid@latest`)

Answer (score -1):

Below solution worked for me!

If your using package.json, add the following to package.json

```
{
 "type": "module"
 ...
}
```

Now use can use `import` with node js

```
// index.js
import { v5 as uuidv5 } from "uuid";

const MY_NAMESPACE = "1b671a64-40d5-491e-99b0-da01ff1f3341";

uuidv5("Hello World", MY_NAMESPACE); // ⇨ 'a572fa0f-9bfa-5103-9882-16394770ad11'
```

Check your output using
`node index.js`